# && cannot be applied to bool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to check if an element in the list contains value true. I m currently getting an error && cannot be applied to bool or service

at this `condition & services.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsPrimaryBusinessLine == true)`:

```
var services = serviceRepository
  .GetServicesByRequestID(newReqeustViewModel.RequestID);


 if (services != null && 
     services.Count != 0 && 
     services.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsPrimaryBusinessLine == true))
```

Service

```
public class Service : BaseEntity
    {
        public int ServiceID { get; set; }
        public int RequestID { get; set; }
        public string BusinessLineCode { get; set; }
        public string BusinessLine { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrimaryBusinessLine { get; set; }
        public int ContractLineSLAID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try like this `if (services != null && services.Count != 0 && services.Any(p => p.IsPrimaryBusinessLine))`

Comment: `services.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsPrimaryBusinessLine == true)` returns `Services` instance. You need to compare it one more time to get `bool` instance which required by `&&` operator.

Answer (score 2):

`FirstOrdefault` returns the first item that matches the condition, i  reckon you want to know if there is such a service because you use it in an `if`, then dont use `FirstOrdefault` but `Any`:

```
if (services != null && services.Any(p => p.IsPrimaryBusinessLine == true))
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use this as a `bool`:

```
services.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsPrimaryBusinessLine == true)
```

But that doesn't resolve to a `bool`, it resolves to an instance of `Service`.  What are you trying to *check* about that service?  That it exists?  From what you're doing, that could be something like:

```
services.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsPrimaryBusinessLine == true) != null
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
services.Any(p => p.IsPrimaryBusinessLine == true)
```

But you need to check for something.  The expression itself needs to resolve to a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Linq Any method.

For example:

```
services.Any(p => p.IsPrimaryBusinessLine == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The best way for your situation:**

```
if (services != null && services.Count != 0 && services.Any(p => p.IsPrimaryBusinessLine))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (services != null && services.Any(p => p.IsPrimaryBusinessLine))
```